# c# behavior on interface implementation

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I've found a behaviour in c# and I would like to know if it's in the specs (and can be expected to work on all platforms and new versions of the .NET runtime) or if it's undefined behaviour that just happens to work but may stop compiling at any time.

So, let's say I want to take existing classes, like these:

```
public class HtmlTextBox
{
  public string Text {get; set;}
}

public class HtmlDiv
{
  public string Text {get; set;}
}
```

now I would really like them to implement a common IText interface, like this one:

```
public interface IText 
{
  string Text {get; }   
}
```

but I can't change the classes directly because they are part of an external library. Now there are various ways to do this, through inheritance or with a decorator.
But I was surprised to find out that doing simply this compiles and works on .NET 4.5 (windows 7 64 bits).

```
public class HtmlTextBox2 : HtmlTextBox, IText {}
public class HtmlDiv2 : HtmlDiv, IText {}
```

That's it. This gets me drop-in replacements for `HtmlTextBox` and `HtmlDiv` that use their existing `Text` property as implementation for `IText`.

I was half-expecting the compiler to yell at me, asking me to provide an explicit re-implementation of `Text`, but on .NET 4.5 this just works:

```
IText h2 = new HtmlTextBox2{Text="Hello World"};
Console.WriteLine(h2.Text);  //OUTPUT: hello world
```

In fact,I've tried the same on mono (whatever version ideone.com is using) and [mono does not yell at me either](http://ideone.com/uFYtlZ)

So I guess I'm good to go, but before trying this on serious code I wanted to check if I've misunderstood what is really happening here or if I can't rely on this to work.

Comment: Yes, that should indeed just work as intended. An interface defines what methods a class should implement (either directly or **throughout the hierarchy**).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. The implementation of an interface's method needs not to be done in the class where the interface is actually applied; it can be in any ancestor class.

The [C# Language Specification 5.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) documents this in section 13.4.4; excerpt of the rule:

> The implementation of a particular interface member `I.M`, where `I` is the interface in which the member `M` is declared, is determined by examining each class or struct `S`, starting with `C` and repeating for each successive base class of `C`, until a match is located

Answer (score 2):

Some clarification to my comment

> Yes, that should indeed just work as intended. An interface defines what methods a class should implement (either directly or **throughout the hierarchy**).

When you define an interface, you could look at it like this:

> An interface's only task is to guarantee that at any point in a class' hierarchy where the interface is defined in the signature, that class has every method in the interface implemented.

Here's a sample situation that hopefully sheds some light:

```
void Main()
{
    Z obj1 = new C();
    Z obj2 = new B();
    Z obj3 = new A();

    Y obj4 = new C();
    Y obj5 = new D();
    Z obj6 = new D();
}

interface Y {
    void someMethod1();
    void someMethod2();
}

interface Z {
    void someMethod3();
}

class A : Z {
    public void someMethod3() { }
}

class B : A {
    public void someMethod1() { }
}

class C : B, Y {
    public void someMethod2() { }
}

class D : C { }
```

This compiles just fine.

As you can see, `B` implements `Y`'s method `someMethod1` after which `C` extends `B` and implements `Y`. All `C` does is provide an implementation for `someMethod2` and at that point the interface definition is reached: the two methods that are defined in `Y` are now available to an object of type `C`.

What's key here is to remember that a class hierarchy are just layers with, amongst others, some methods. At the moment in a hierarchy where you say "this class needs to implement every method defined in `<SomeInterface>`" you basically have to make sure that each of them is available to your class at that point. Inheritance tells us that we can use the methods of a superclass, which means that by implementing your method in a baseclass you have satisfied the condition.

Sidenote: all of this is written without `abstract` methods in mind, they're a little different.